# How to programatically scroll a scrollviewer and retain the animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, scrollviewer

I have a page whose contents are horizontally wider than the phone, sort of like a Panorama but without all the parallax stuff, and I want to let the user flick to scroll, and also press a button to scroll to specified offsets within the scrollviewer.  ScrollToHorizontalOffset works fine for the button, except that it loses the animation, and I want to retain the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a very similar thing. I have created WizardControl and WizardPage user controls. The user can flick between pages or use next and previous buttons.

I have created a slide effect animation to move between pages. Here is the code:

```
Storyboard sb = SlideEffect(MainPanel, (-_pageWidth * pagesToMove));
sb.Completed += Slide_Completed;
sb.Begin();


private Storyboard SlideEffect(UIElement controlToAnimate, double positionToMove)
{
    //Get position of stackpanel
    GeneralTransform gt = controlToAnimate.TransformToVisual(MainGrid);
    Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    //add new storyboard and animation
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation { To = p.X + positionToMove };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, controlToAnimate);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("(controlToAnimate.RenderTransform).(TransformTranslate.X)"));

    ExponentialEase ee = new ExponentialEase { Exponent = 6.0, EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
    da.EasingFunction = ee;

    sb.Children.Add(da);
    return sb;
}
```

MainPanel is a horizontal stack panel. Wizard pages are added to it.

_pageWidth matters as this works in both portrait and landscape mode.

pagestoMove is used as I have a button to return directly to the first page.

**UPDATE - added Wizard main panel def and add page method**

```
<StackPanel
    x:Name="MainPanel"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    Margin="0,0,0,10"
    Width="480">

    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform
            X="0" />
    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

</StackPanel>


public void AddPage(WizardPageControl page)
{
    MainPanel.Width += _pageWidth;

    page.PageWidth = _pageWidth;

    double newRight = (MainPanel.Width - _pageWidth) * -1;
    MainPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, newRight, 10);

    MainPanel.Children.Add(page);

    _wizardPageList.Add(page);

    TotalPages++;
}
```

Comment: I also eventually got this to work with a scrollviewer by attaching to the scrollbars as described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95746/Exposing-and-Binding-to-a-Silverlight-ScrollViewer.aspx
But your solution is much nicer, thanks!

Comment: Jumped the gun on that last comment, I wonder how you solved the following problems:  Horizontal stackpanel clips anything wider than the screen, I got it to stop doing that by giving it a negative margin but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  After having done that, I'm trying to figure out how to get the stackpanel to scroll in reaction to flicks.  Did you use a toolkit gesturelistener to trigger the above animation on flicks?

Comment: have added panel xaml and add page method to answer above. Yes I used the toolkit gesture listener.

Comment: Ok, got this to work finally.  We should be clear here that we're reinventing the wheel and basically rebuilding a scrollviewer.  I'll also mention that its important to set CacheMode=BitmapCache on the parent panel to get decent scrolling performance.  A full treatment of the problem can be found here:  http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/20/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx